# How to return more values to the calling function in Python3 and display the result, currently it's printing only first value without increment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return-value

Problem: Finding the Odd numbers within given range(inclusive). `l` = left range, `r` = right range. For example:

Input:

```
l=2
r=5
```

Expected Output:

```
3
5
```

As I have already done this program in one method shown in below,

```
def findOddNumber(l,r):
for num in range(l,r):
    if(num%2!=0):
        print(num)
l=2
r=5
res=[]
findOddNumber(l,r)
```

Instead of printing in user defined function like above, I'm expecting to return the values to calling function, I have tried like this:

```
def findOddNumber(l,r):
for num in range(l,r):
    if(num%2!=0):
        return num
l=2
r=5
res=findOddNumber(l,r)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
3
```

Expected output:

```
3
5
```

Comment: You can only `return` once. You could build and return a sequence (list, tuple, ...) or look into generators that can `yield` multiple values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list and instead of printing just append to the list. Then you return the list

```
def findOddNumber(l,r):
    res=[]
    for num in range(l,r+1):
        if(num%2!=0):
            res.append(num)
    return res

l=2
r=5
res=findOddNumber(l,r)
print(res)
```

Comment: @Goutham Vijay sorry, my fault. You should change **range(l,r)** with **range(l,r+1)** because the final value in range is not included

Comment: Thanks for the help....it was indentation error